# Perl. Print each element of array for matrix

Tags: arrays, perl

I created a function, which generates a random matrix and pushed it into array.

```
sub gen {
  my $x = int(rand($_[0]-1)+1);
  my $y = int(rand($_[1]-1)+1);
  my $matrix = [ map [ map int(rand($_[2]-1)+1), 1..$x ], 1..$y ];
}

push (my @gen, gen(5,10,5))
```

I just want to sort elements in each array:

```
sub sort {

  foreach my $value (@gen) {

    foreach (@$value) {
      foreach my $_ (sort {$b <=> $a} @{$value}) {
        print "$_";
      }
      print "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

It gives me only references to arrays, but I thought it should be scalars.

**Output**:

```
ARRAY(0xdbef68)ARRAY(0xdbeef0)ARRAY(0xdbee78)ARRAY(0xdbee00)ARRAY(0xdbed88)
ARRAY(0xdbef68)ARRAY(0xdbeef0)ARRAY(0xdbee78)ARRAY(0xdbee00)ARRAY(0xdbed88)
ARRAY(0xdbef68)ARRAY(0xdbeef0)ARRAY(0xdbee78)ARRAY(0xdbee00)ARRAY(0xdbed88)
ARRAY(0xdbef68)ARRAY(0xdbeef0)ARRAY(0xdbee78)ARRAY(0xdbee00)ARRAY(0xdbed88)
ARRAY(0xdbef68)ARRAY(0xdbeef0)ARRAY(0xdbee78)ARRAY(0xdbee00)ARRAY(0xdbed88)
```

Comment: Are you sure `int(rand($n-1)+1)` does what you want? It generates random integers from `1` to `$n-1` inclusive.

Comment: i just wanted to avoid creating empty matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is returning a *reference* to an array of references `[[...],[...]]`, but you're treating it like an direct array of references`([...],[...])`.

The easiest solution is to just make the function return an array of arrays.  The following also makes your code more self-documenting by assigning your parameters to named variables:

```
sub gen{
    my ($max_cols, $max_rows, $max_val) = @_;

    my $cols = 1 + int rand($max_cols - 1);
    my $rows = 1 + int rand($max_rows - 1);
    my @matrix = map {
        [map {1 + int rand($max_val - 1)} (1..$cols)]
    } (1..$rows);

    return @matrix;   # <--- returns an array now
}

my @gen = gen(5,10,5);  # <--- so you can assign to an array
```

Alternatively, if you kept the same function, you could assign back to a scalar and dereference it:

```
my $array_ref = gen(5,10,5);

for (@$array_ref) {
```